# Generate list of datasets with randomly selected features in R

Tags: r, feature-selection

I have a dataset with 20 features. I wish to create a list of datasets with random subsets of features from the original data set.
For example - `[dataset[, c(1,3,4)], dataset[, c(2,3,5,11,20)]]`.

I am trying the following code for the same

```
selectors = array(runif(2000), dim=c(100, 20, 1))
list_datasets = vector("list", 100)
i = 1
while(i < 100)
  list_datasets[[i]] = dataset[, selectors[i,,1] > 0.5]
  i = i + 1
```

Here, my `dataset` has 20 features and I need 100 datasets with random features out of these 20 features. So I have created `selectors` array, by initially creating a vector of size 2000 with random values and then making it 100*20. In the `while` loop, I have then tried to add a feature to `list_datasets[[i]]` only if random value generated for it was greater than 0.5 . Hopefully, I was able to explain myself

But this is very slow. I am new to R and want to know what is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to make 100 (partial) copies of the data. Instead, just use your matrix `selectors` and when you want, say, the 42nd data set, you use `dataset[, selectors[42, ]]`.

Comment: And turn `selectors` into a boolean matrix, `selectors = selectors < 0.5`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if I understand your setup, so correct me if I missed something.  My understanding is that you have a dataset (I created a fake dataset of size 100 rows x 20 features) and want to create 100 new datasets using a random subset of features.  You generate a random subset of features by generating random uniform values and checking if each is > 0.5.

I have two options here, one using `lapply` and one using a `for` loop.

The apply functions are generally faster than loops (and I think you want to use a `for` loop, not a `while` loop here anyway).

Other changes:

1) Use a boolean mask as @Krash suggested, since you can check if each value is greater than 0.5 outside the loop, as whether or not it is does not depend on `i`.

2) `selectors` can be 2d

```
set.seed(123)

# Original dataset: assume it's 100 x 20 features
dataset <- array(rnorm(2000), dim = c(100, 20))
```

```
## Original (Option 0: while loop)

system.time({
  # Select features: 100 x 20 x 1 (one row per dataset)
  selectors = array(runif(2000), dim = c(100, 20, 1));

  # Initialize list
  list_datasets = vector("list", 100);

  # Fill in list
  i = 1;
  while(i < 100) {
    list_datasets[[i]] = dataset[, selectors[i,,1] > 0.5];
    i = i + 1 # This causes an off-by-one error, as list_datasets[[100]] is never filled in
  }
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.006   0.000   0.006 

# Option 1: for loop
system.time({
  # Select: boolean mask: 100 x 20 (need one row to create each dataset)
  selectors = array(runif(2000), dim = c(100, 20));
  selectors = selectors < 0.5

  # Initialize list
  list_datasets = vector("list", 100);

  # Fill in list
  for (i in 1:100) {
    list_datasets[[i]] = dataset[ , selectors[i, ]] 
  }
})

##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.004   0.000   0.005

# Option 2: lapply
system.time({
  # Select: boolean mask: 100 x 20 (need one row to create each dataset)
  selectors = array(runif(2000), dim = c(100, 20));
  selectors = selectors < 0.5

  # Fill in list
  list_datasets <- lapply(1:100, FUN = function(x) dataset[ , selectors[x, ]])
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.003   0.000   0.003
```

Obviously the amount of time statements take to run vary each time you run the statements, but hopefully some of these suggested changes will improve the speed.

Just as a check to make sure the code did what I wanted it to do:

```
# Check number of cols per dataset
list_datasets %>% 
  purrr::map_int(~ncol(.))

##  [1]  8  7  9 12 11 13 11 10 10 14 14  7  8 10 10  9 14 10  6 11 13  8  7  8 10 12  9 11  9  9 13
## [32] 12  8 14 11 11  8 10 11  8 10 13 12 10  6 10 10 12  9  9 10 11  7  8 11  9 11  9  7  9  9 11
## [63] 14  9  9  9  9 13 13 14 12  9 10  9 12  8 11 14  9  7 12  7  6 11 11  7  9  8 12 10 12  9 11
## [94] 13 12 16  9  8 11 10
```

Other thoughts: Rather than creating a `selectors` array via random uniforms with each row corresponding to a new dataset, you could add a line like this inside your loop (or `lapply` `FUN`).

```
include_feature <- sample(0:1, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
include_feature
## [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```